# Bootstrap From: make width 100% on every screen

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a good looking responsive search form with CSS Bootstrap.

Following is my html and bootstrap code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" style="">
                    <div class="row">               
                        <div class=" col-md-4 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-icon"></span></span>
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Keyword</span>-->
                                <input type="text" id="searchjob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
                            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe form-icon"></span></span>
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Location</span>-->
                                <select class="form-control">
                                <option>London</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
            </div>


                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign form-icon"></span></span> 
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Category</span>-->
                                <select class="form-control" style="">
                                <option>Administration</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 form-group group-1">                        
                            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-warning form-top" style="margin-top: -1px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
```

This is how it looks on laptop screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwPmV.jpg)

This is how it looks on mobile device:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjPRG.jpg)

As you can see it looks very nice on mobile devices with full width of form inputs, but it does not look good on my laptop screen. I want to make full width on every device screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code to :`<div class="container"> your code </div>` so it will look better.

```html
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" role="form" style="">
                    <div class="row">               
                        <div class=" col-md-4 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-icon"></span></span>
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Keyword</span>-->
                                <input type="text" id="searchjob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keywords">
                            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe form-icon"></span></span>
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Location</span>-->
                                <select class="form-control">
                                <option>London</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
            </div>


                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group group-1">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="btn-info input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign form-icon"></span></span> 
                                <!--<span class="btn-info input-group-addon form-icon">Category</span>-->
                                <select class="form-control" style="">
                                <option>Administration</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                <option>Kabul</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 form-group group-1">                        
                            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-warning form-top" style="margin-top: -1px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

To get better result, see the documents for `container` here [Container Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)